# Using mobile gestures(touch) in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4 and am looking for a way to implement a good tab touch swipe navigation for mobile users with a swipe transition to the next tab view without hammerjs.

Does anyone know a good way to implement a tab swipe-based navigation for Angular 4? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. : )

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, HammerJS is pretty good for swipe gestures. Why not use Jquery Mobile? and then on swipe event navigate.

There is also this library I used, but works with 1 full page with many sections and has swipe.

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/